# How does Backbone.JS handle models with calculated attributes

Tags: backbone.js, mustache

I'm using Backbone.JS with Mustache, so to render my tempaltes I call MyModel.toJSON(). This leaves me with only access to attributes. How can I have some attributes that are always calculated?

I looked at the Backbone.JS documentation and it might work to override validate() but this seems like a hack and may lead to infinite loops.

I also tried making an attribute be a function instead of a value, but Mustache doesn't get a value when I try to use it.

Comment: Override toJSON: have it call the original toJSON, then add your calculated attributes to the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I'm currently doing it. I do the calculations when initializing a model, and adding a listener for changes to the model to recalculate automatically.

```
...
initialize: function() {
  console.log('Lead:initialize');
  _.bindAll(this, 'validate', 'calculate');
  this.bind('change', this.setCalculations, this);
  this.setCalculations();
},
setCalculations: function() {
  this.set({ calculations: this.calculate() }, { silent: true });
},
calculate: function() {
  // do the calculations and return
},
...
```

Comment: Did you do something different to prevent it from creating an infinite loop? I tried this and I can create a model, but then the first time I set anything on it I get an infinite loop.

Comment: Oh! Sorry! I forgot the `, { silent: true }` within `setCalculations`

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if i understand the question correctly, but:

Can't You pass the actual model to mustache? so for example when you render

```
render: ->    
rendered_content = @template({model: @model})  
$(@.el).html rendered_content
@
```

You are passing the actual model to template. Then you have a template

```
<td class="quantity">         
  <input type="text" value="<%= model.get('quantity') %>" name="quantity" />
</td>


<td>
  <%= model.getTotalPrice() %>
</td>
```

And in model you declare getTotalPrice()

```
getTotalPrice: ->
   total_price = @get('price') * @get('quantity')
   total_price + total_price * @get('tax_rate')
```

I actually never pass @model.toJSON in my templates, alawys the actual model.

Comment: That doesn't work because Mustache (http://mustache.github.com/) is intentionally logic-less. You can get attributes off the object but you can't call .get()